# Expression Tree throws error

Tags: .net, expression-trees, visual-studio-lightswitch, claims-based-identity

In my VS LIGHTSWITCH 2013 portal application I allow the user to create tiles that link to other internal apps. When a new tile is create a Role with the name 'TileTitle + " User"' is created. This way I can show and hide tiles based on a users roles. However when trying to filter the tile entities in the query filter method I get some error about not being able to use the IsInRole method.

After some digging I decided to give expression trees a try, and this is what I came up with:

```
partial void TileLinks_Filter(ref Expression<Func<TileLink, bool>> filter)
{
    ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TileLink), "e");
    MemberExpression ti = Expression.Property(p, "Title");
    MethodInfo m2 = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });


    Type t = this.Application.User.GetType();
    MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("IsInRole");

    Expression filterExpression = Expression.IsTrue(Expression.Call(Expression.Call(m2, ti, Expression.Constant(" User")), m));

    filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<TileLink, bool>>(filterExpression, p); 

    // e => this.Application.User.IsInRole(e.Title + " User"); 
    // this is what I would like to do
 }
```

This however does not work, and I am left with this very odd error message.

```
Method 'Boolean IsInRole(System.String)' declared on type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.String'
```

Please help me filter my data based on dynamically generated roles!

Answer (score 0):

You've got your arguments reversed in the outer call to `Expression.Call`. If you broke your code out a bit, you'd end up with this:

```
var titlePlusUser = Expression.Call(m2, ti, Expression.Constant(" User"));
var isInRole = Expression.Call(titlePlusUser, m); // <<-- !!!
Expression filterExpression = Expression.IsTrue(isInRole);
```

This is instructing it to use `e.Title + "User"` as the object instance to call `IsInRole` on.

Instead you need to produce another expression that knows how to get `this.Application.User`, and pass that expression in as the first parameter.

```
var isInRole = Expression.Call(applicationUser, m, titlePlusUser);
```